# Не могу понять ошибки valgrind

Tags: отладка, память, c, valgrind

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть подозрение на утечку памяти в программе, запустил через valgrind. Некоторые вещи я не понимаю, например, вот здесь где мне искать ошибку в программе:

```
==5088== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5088==    at 0x52A382F: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BB75B: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA617: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA720: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52B8E1E: localtime (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x8152643: arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() (arlogging-i386.cpp:72)
==5088==    by 0x8152C44: arlogging_i386::Logging::AppendLog(std::string, int) (arlogging-i386.cpp:125)
==5088==    by 0x808200D: AppendLog(std::string, char const*, int) (logs.cpp:21)
==5088==    by 0x806A2FD: Database::Initialization() (database.cpp:153)
==5088==    by 0x806DD5D: Database::CreateTableIfNeeded() (database.cpp:592)
==5088==    by 0x806A0B8: Database::Database() (database.cpp:127)
==5088==    by 0x80AE30B: Recorder::Recorder() (recorder.cpp:29)
==5088==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5088==    at 0x40265DC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==5088==    by 0x52BB2B6: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA617: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA720: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52B8E1E: localtime (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x8152643: arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() (arlogging-i386.cpp:72)
==5088==    by 0x8152C44: arlogging_i386::Logging::AppendLog(std::string, int) (arlogging-i386.cpp:125)
==5088==    by 0x808200D: AppendLog(std::string, char const*, int) (logs.cpp:21)
==5088==    by 0x806A2FD: Database::Initialization() (database.cpp:153)
==5088==    by 0x806DD5D: Database::CreateTableIfNeeded() (database.cpp:592)
==5088==    by 0x806A0B8: Database::Database() (database.cpp:127)
==5088==    by 0x80AE30B: Recorder::Recorder() (recorder.cpp:29)
```

Или вот еще странное что-то:

```
==5088== Invalid read of size 4
==5088==    at 0x52A383B: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BADCA: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA7C2: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52B8E1E: localtime (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x8152643: arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() (arlogging-i386.cpp:72)
==5088==    by 0x8152C44: arlogging_i386::Logging::AppendLog(std::string, int) (arlogging-i386.cpp:125)
==5088==    by 0x808200D: AppendLog(std::string, char const*, int) (logs.cpp:21)
==5088==    by 0x806A2FD: Database::Initialization() (database.cpp:153)
==5088==    by 0x806DD5D: Database::CreateTableIfNeeded() (database.cpp:592)
==5088==    by 0x806A0B8: Database::Database() (database.cpp:127)
==5088==    by 0x80AE30B: Recorder::Recorder() (recorder.cpp:29)
==5088==    by 0x808E738: Nvr::Nvr(int) (nvr.cpp:18)
==5088==  Address 0x65d0124 is 12 bytes inside a block of size 14 alloc'd
==5088==    at 0x40265DC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==5088==    by 0x52B9D9D: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BBAA2: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA617: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52BA720: ??? (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x52B8E1E: localtime (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so)
==5088==    by 0x8152643: arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() (arlogging-i386.cpp:72)
==5088==    by 0x8152C44: arlogging_i386::Logging::AppendLog(std::string, int) (arlogging-i386.cpp:125)
==5088==    by 0x808200D: AppendLog(std::string, char const*, int) (logs.cpp:21)
==5088==    by 0x806A2FD: Database::Initialization() (database.cpp:153)
==5088==    by 0x806DD5D: Database::CreateTableIfNeeded() (database.cpp:592)
==5088==    by 0x806A0B8: Database::Database() (database.cpp:127)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик! Но я все равно не могу найти проблему.. Функция arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() моя, но там ничего криминального нет:

    char * Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength()
    {
      static char OutString[DT_BUF_SIZE];
      time_t t;
      struct tm *tm;

      t = time(NULL);
      tm = localtime(&t);
      if (tm == NULL) return NULL;
      if (!strftime(OutString, DT_BUF_SIZE, "%d.%m.%Y %T", tm))
        {
          return NULL;
        }
      return OutString;
    }

Comment: void Logging::AppendLog(string Text, int log_level)
    {
      ofstream LogFileStream;
      string LogText;
      txt = Text;

      LogFileStream.open(FullLogName.c_str(), ios::app);
      if (!LogFileStream.is_open())
        {
          return;
        }
      LogText.assign(GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength());
      LogText = "> " + LogText + " " + txt;
      if (log_level <= LLevel)
        {
          LogFileStream.write(LogText.c_str(), LogText.length());
          LogFileStream.close();
        }
    }

Comment: @Xaruch: У меня лимит комментариев вышел. По поводу другого сообщения, лучше задайте отдельный вопрос, и обязательно разместите логи.

Comment: @Xaruch, там у меня тоже комментарии закончились.

А ругается (IMHO) на `gmtime()`. Видимо, надо заменить на `gmtime_r()` 

(по той же причине, почему заменяли `localtime()` на localtime_r()`).

Comment: @Xaruch, отвечаю здесь, на Ваш комментарий (про strdup) там.

- Да, память, выделяемую `strdup()` надо удалять, вызывая `free()`.

- Да, `strdup` может вернуть 0, в серьезных программах это нужно проверять.

- Функция `gettimeofday()` возвращает микросекунды (просто разделите их на 1000 (если хотите "поточнее" прибавьте 1, но тут надо корректировать, если получится 1000) и добавьте в конец буфера).

Например:

      gettimeofday(&td, 0);
      sprintf(buf + strftime(buf, size, "%d.%m.%Y %T", &tm),
              ".%.3d", td.tv_usec / 1000);

Comment: @Xaruch, у Вас уже тоже комментарии заканчиваются?

В почте вижу:

    Дык.. нету у меня определения функции gettimeofday в файле time.h

а тут нигде нет...

--

См. в `man gettimeofday`:

`#include <sys/time.h>`.


Кстати, ОС-то у Вас какая?

--

Похоже, пора Вам новую тему(ы) (вопросы от ... "как можно написать ...") открывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ошибка говорит, что вы не инициализировали какую-то переменную, и считываете её значение. По стандарту это запрещено. (Надеюсь, вы знаете, что такое [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) и понимаете, почему допускать его категорически нельзя. Если нет, спросите вашего архитектора.)

Судя по всему, вы строите из этой переменной `localtime` в функции `arlogging_i386::Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength()`. (Это ваша функция? Если нет, то проблемная переменная скорее всего в вызове `AppendLog` из `Database::Initialization()` (database.cpp:153).)

Вторая ошибка, судя по всему, следствие первой.

До утечки памяти дело ещё не дошло, исправьте сначала эти ошибки.

Comment: @Xaruch: Хм. И правда, в вашем коде не видно ничего криминального.

А может быть, что вы пользуетесь функцией `Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength()` одновременно из нескольких потоков? Согласно [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime), `localtime` не потокобезопасна, т. к. возвращает ссылку на статический буфер внутри себя (а значит, при одновременном вызове из двух потоков одно из значений портится). То же, кстати, относится и к `static char OutString`.

Comment: И правда.. потоков около 20..
Спасибо, буду думать как это исправить.

Comment: @Xaruch: Если в вашей версии C поддерживается, воспользуйтесь localtime_r. И переместите буфер OutString в стек (то есть уберите static).

Или вы можете использовать [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) (вы же пишете на C++, да?) вместе с `stringstream`'ом для форматирования.

Comment: Если я убираю модификатор static для переменной OutString, то компилятор выдает ошибку 'Address of local variable returned'.

Comment: @Xaruch, это естественно, но посмотрите на все это чуть под другим углом (сказал бы *функциональным*, но этот термин уже давно означает несколько другое).

Переделайте `char * Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength()` на

    char * Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength(char buf[]) {
      time_t t = time(0);
      struct tm tm;
      if (localtime_r(&t, &tm))
        if (strftime(buf, DT_BUF_SIZE, "%d.%m.%Y %T", &tm))
          return buf;
      return 0;
    }

ну, и вызывайте ее так

    ....
    char buf[DT_BUF_SIZE];
    LogText.assign(GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength(buf));
    ....

Comment: Угу. Пусть вызывающая функция _сама_ поставляет буфер. Я бы только ещё передавал его длину на вход. (А на выход, возможно, флаг ошибки?)

Comment: Да, особенно, если функция используется в нескольких местах, то размер буфера нужен.

А по поводу кода ошибки -- даже и не знаю, а какие тут, собственно, могут быть ошибки и что разумного можно вытянуть из их анализа?

(надо `man`-ы внимательно изучать...)

Comment: @avp: Ошибка может быть, например, если буфер слишком маленький.

А вот разумного анализа здесь не видно, поэтому я бы ограничился флагом (была ошибка/не было).

Comment: @VladD, так ведь, 0 и возвращается при любой ошибке.

А по большому счету в рабочем коде этой функции проверки вообще не нужны.

Мне кажется, что размер буфера и ошибка в строке форматов для `strftime()` *обязаны* ловиться при начальном тестировании (отладке).

Т.е. при работе программы остается только `localtime_r()`. 

Проверять `time()`, про ошибки в которй в `man` пишут:

    No errors are defined

наверное не стоит.

Возможно, что-то можно сломать в системе в настройках TZ и т.п. (и `localtime` вернет nil), но что именно, не знаю.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, я как раз и сам к такому же варианту пришел))
Спасибо, avp!

Comment: Тогда получим такой код

    char * Logging::GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength(char buf[], int size) {
      time_t t = time(0);
      struct tm tm;
      return strftime(buf, size, "%d.%m.%Y %T", localtime_r(&t, &tm));
    }

--

Кстати, мы не знаем что делают с буфером в `LogText.assign()`.

Если его загоняют в динамическую память, то может лучше сразу

     #define GetCurrDateTimeFixedLength() ({time_t t = time(0); struct tm tm; char buf[100]; strdup(strftime(buf, size, "%d.%m.%Y %T", localtime_r(&t, &tm)));})

(или если `#define` не нравятся, то `static inline char *` ....)

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, strdup() же выделяет память, значит где-то потом ее нужно чистить? И опять же strdup() может возвратить NULL...
И кстати, заодно еще вопрос - как бы тут добавить миллисекунды ко времени?